# Invalid object name 'dbo.ApplicationUsers'.?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am create small crud operation on user using entity framework code first.now i need the delete user using store procedure so i find many links getting solution for the how to use store procedure in EF.so i am write this code for that.but i m write this code and method OnModelCreating() in class and go for the login that time getting error like this 'Invalid object name 'dbo.ApplicationUsers'. i am comment this method login very well work but uncomment this code getting error.

this is my class :

```
  using System.Security.Claims;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
  using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
  using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
  using System.Data.Entity;
  using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
  using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

  namespace abc.Models
  {
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.    
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }       
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }


    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<List<Users>> GetUserInfo()
    { 
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<List<Users>>("GetUserInfo");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) // this method wroite after getting error
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Delete(u => u.HasName("DeleteUserById", "dbo")
                                            .Parameter(b => b.id, "userid"))
            );
    }  

}
}
```

this is Users class :

```
[Table("Users")]
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long id { get; set; }

    public string firstname { get; set; }

    public string lastname { get; set; }       

    public string contactnumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime datetime { get; set; }

}
```

this is my class any one know how can do that and fix it this error.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to have both `ApplicationUser` and `Users` ? `IdentityDbContext` already defines a `DbSet<ApplicationUser>`, why don't you use that instead ?

Comment: guys what you want to say idk i am new for EF and idenetity can you please give me hint

Comment: you mean modelBuilder.Entity<Users>() here Users to replace ApplicationUsers???

Comment: but in my db Users is new table so i can used users.

Comment: You must have a table in your database, AspNetUsers, right ? Anyway, show us the content of Users.

Comment: @dbraillon can you please help me for fix it this error

Comment: If you really want another table that handle your Users informations, choose another name, it seems to mess with the ApplicationUser used by Identity stuff. And change the name of the DbSet, it's hidding the DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users inside IdentityDbContext.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140155/discussion-between-coderwill-and-dbraillon).

Comment: If you prefer to add those informations to existing ApplicationUser, I suggest you to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#ap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) // this method wroite after getting error
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
        .MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Delete(u => u.HasName("DeleteUserById", "dbo")
                                        .Parameter(b => b.id, "userid"))
        );
}
```

Remove first three lines and add

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

So it will be

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
        .MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Delete(u => u.HasName("DeleteUserById", "dbo")
                                        .Parameter(b => b.id, "userid"))
        );
}
```

Comment: hi dbraillon can you please one help me??

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error running this sql command

```
create view myschema.ApplicationUser as select * from myschema.AspNetUsers
```

The solution of dbraillon generates a new error to me:

Invalid object name dbo.AspNetUsers

because my AspNetUsers table is not in the dbo schema and i need to override the default onModelCreating